# Prove $P(X<\infty)=1 \implies E(X)<\infty$

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $X$ is any continuous random variable. Is it possible to prove that if $P(X<\infty)=1$ (that is, $X$ is finite almost sure), then $E(X)$ is also finite. Thus, to prove that:
$P(X<\infty)=1 \implies E(X)<\infty$.

Comment: No because it is not true.

Answer (score 5):

No, for the simple reason that it is not true.

For example, take a random variable with density

$$p(x) = \frac{C}{x^2}$$

on $[1,\infty)$, where $$C=\frac{1}{\int_1^\infty \frac1{x^2}}$$ (it doesn't matter what $C$ is, it's a finite number).

Then, $P(X<\infty)=1$, however $E(X)=\infty$ (both these facts should be easy to prove).

> *Note*:
>
> You can also replace the $2$ in my example with any number $d\in(1, 2]$

Comment: @alex.jordan Dangit. So sloppy early in the morning. I think you should rewrite my answer and get the rep for it now...

Comment: No no, +1. It's good.

Comment: And if you restrict attention to random variables with densities over $(-\infty, \infty)$?

Comment: @cube You can use my example, just say that the probability of the random variable being below $1$ is $0$.

Comment: Ok, but let's say there is a positive probability over the whole real line, only approaching 0 as $x\to\pm\infty$ (that is, the density function is not censored as it would be when putting $P(X<1)=0$ in your example? Or then, what additional restrictions should apply for $P(X<\infty)=1\Longrightarrow E(X)<\infty$ to hold?

Comment: @cube You can use my variable to define the variable with density $$p(x)=\begin{cases}e^{x-1}: & x\leq 1\\ \frac{D}{x^2}\end{cases}$$

and find a variable $D$ such that the integral of $p$ is $1$. Then the variable has a nonzero density everywhere, but still, $E(X)=\infty$.